# Apache Cassandra for ZOS (s390x) architecture

Tags: cassandra, zos

I would like to know if Apache Cassandra has support for ZOS server with s390x. I have been searching on the official documentation but I could not find some references about it.

Comment: I found this, I hope it helps - [Building Apache Cassandra 3.11](https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Building-Apache-Cassandra-3.11)

Comment: And here is the link to more versions being ported on z Systems - [Building Apache Cassandra](https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Building-Apache-Cassandra)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will check it

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles across this, wanted to make it clear that "s390x" usually refers to Linux running on IBM zSeries hardware...yes, you'll have no trouble finding Cassandra ports there - it's just Linux - but that's a different thing than z/OS (which is an entirely different mainframe operating system and has nothing to do with Linux)

Comment: We have been running cassandra on s390x successfully. Now trying to port to USS (z/OS). Is there any porting instructions available?   The first hurdle is the NATIVE code (JNA) dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You could compile from source like some of the comments suggest.

Alternatively, consider running Cassandra as a container as there already exists an s390x image https://hub.docker.com/r/ubuntu/cassandra

You could run this in zOS using zOS Container Extensions, or you could use Linux on Z!